# tinymce 5 button with function insertContent create unnecessary elements

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I can't understend where the  elements come from and how to remove them.

```
        setup: function (editor) { 
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('mathLine', {
        icon: 'code-sample',
        tooltip: 'mathLine',
         onAction: function (_) {
        editor.insertContent('{literal}'+'\\\\('+'\\)'+'{/literal}');
         },
          });
```

[And i got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpUy9.jpg)

How fix this? I cant use "invalid_elements:", and need get "{literal}\(\){/literal}"

Comment: I made a TinyMCE Fiddle with your API call to insert content and I don't see all of that extraneous code you do:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/iMhaab

The resultant code is:  `<p>{literal}\\(\){/literal}</p>`

Comment: Michael Fromin, Thx .Yes, strange things should work. Thanks again, I solved the problem by another way. Found error - сonfiguring MathJax - placed after CDN, inlineMath $..$ not always render.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.